# How can I run webpack without all the built-in plugins

Tags: webpack

`webpack` is a powerful compiler I know, I feed some es6 files and it gives me the es5 files.

Here is my case, I just want to know the dependencies about javascript files with the `require` statement. I know `webpack` can gives me the data I want, but one plugin(I don't exactly know which it is) will always output a bundle file that is useless for me. Nevertheless, there are many useless built-in plugins affecting performance.

So, here is the question, how can I remove all the built-in plugins loaded by default?

Comment: `webpack` is not a compiler, it's a module bundler. The compilation from es6 to es5 is done via babel most of the time. When you simply use webpack, there aren't any plugins loaded by default, you have to explicitly mention them in the loaders. So I don't understand the question, what is your problem and what do you want to achieve? Do you have a sample project to share?

Comment: Yes, a tiny error about webpack :).   I mean **plugin** not **loader**, plugin and loader are different things, I know loader will not loaded by default.